# How to read nested API links within the JSON file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

If my JSON file is coming out like this, what needs to happen is go to the API link within the u_parent and populate the values from that API link with sysparm_display_value=true into the df. Possible? I need to do this because this API link is giving me the same name and parent and only the link in u_parent will give me the correct parent details.

```
{
            "u_name": "******",
            "u_parent": {
                "display_value": "*****",
                "link": "https://*****.******.com/api/now/table/u_region_hierarchies/ed7f652f1b29341051380e93cc4bcbd7"
            },
            "sys_id": "159967df1b75601070bfdb9cbc4bcb35",
            "sys_updated_by": "mlarcheveque",
            "sys_created_on": "01/24/2021 17:31:26",
            "sys_mod_count": "1",
            "u_active": "true",
            "u_region_id": "**********",
            "sys_updated_on": "07/30/2021 14:13:33",
            "sys_tags": "",
            "sys_created_by": "admin"
        },
```

The API link from that u_parent displays the following values and i want the display value from u_parent

```
{
    "result": {
        "u_name": "*****",
        "u_parent": {
            "display_value": "*****",
            "link": "https://*****.*****.com/api/now/table/u_region_hierarchies/6d7f252f1b29341051380e93cc4bcbd7"
        },
        "sys_id": "217f652f1b29341051380e93cc4bcbd4",
        "sys_updated_by": "mlarcheveque",
        "u_id": "*****",
        "sys_created_on": "07/30/2021 14:11:49",
        "sys_mod_count": "0",
        "sys_updated_on": "07/30/2021 14:11:49",
        "sys_tags": "",
        "sys_created_by": "mlarcheveque"
    }
}
```

So i am thinking this would involve a do while loop that goes through each row and gets the value from the nested API link